# Firebase database is giving an error that firebase.database.rel is not a function in web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been experimenting with Firebase recently. I have implemented Firebase Authentication in my apps but i am experiencing an error with Firebase realtime-database. I have searched online but there are no results for this exact problem. I have been trying to fix it but i can't, I have tried everything.
Here is my image:
[Firebase Database error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqmPW.jpg)

Here is my **HTML** code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "-----API KEY-------",
    authDomain: "-----AUTH DOMAIN-----",
    databaseURL: "----DATABASE URL----",
    projectId: "----PROJECT ID----",
    storageBucket: "-----STORAGE BUCKET----",
    messagingSenderId: "----SENDER ID----",
    appId: "-----APP ID-----",
    measurementId: "----MEASURMENT ID -----"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    </script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" id="names">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" id="rollno">
        <button onclick="savedata()">Save Data</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have changed **firebase-app.js** to **firebase.js** at **Line 8** in the HTML above but It didn't fix my problem. Also here is my **Javascript**:

```
function savedata() {
    var name = document.getElementById("names");
    var roll = document.getElementById("rollno");

    var student = {
        name: name.value,
        rollno: roll.value
    }
    firebase.database().rel('student').set(student)
}
```

Right here, i am creating an object student in my firebase realtime-database ,in which i am going to add the values of name and roll no which will all be collected from the user input.

Comment: The method is called `ref()` (for *reference*), not `rel()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method "rel".  Perhaps you meant [ref()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database#ref).